# Arrows not showing on mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I have found a carousel template online that works great but the mobile version does not show the arrows and I cannot find why (if it is in the javascript or in the CSS)

https://github.com/morgansson/g-scrolling-carousel

thank you

I have tries to change true for false in many places on the javascript but I am useless

I should paste the entire file beacause I can't find the problem

Comment: It is by design, mobile devices have a touch screen which enables them to swipe left/right to show the next image in the carousel whilst desktops don't , so the desktops need those arrows while mobile devices don't. To answer your question you're probably having a media query that hides the arrows based on a size range most likely `<=930px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in `jquery.gScrollingCarousel.css` file:

```
 @media (pointer: coarse) {
      .jc-right,
      .jc-left {
        display: none !important;
      }
    }
```

This means if the device includes a pointing device of limited accuracy like touch, this CSS will be applied. You can remove this if you want to have arrows on mobile.